# Validating using vform in Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

am using Vue Js and Laravel in my application. My code has products and images. I am able to upload images using axios but when I add vform to validate all my images , no image is passed to the controller. When I interchange  axios.post('/senddata', formData, config) to  this.form.post('/senddata', formData, config) the other data is passed but images are null.
Here is my code;

```
             saveImageData(){
              var self=this;
              const config = {
                    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                }
                document.getElementById('upload-file').value=[];
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('title', this.form.title);
                formData.append('description', this.form.description);
                formData.append('location', this.form.location);
                formData.append('price', this.form.price);
                 for(let i=0;i<this.form.images.length;i++){
                formData.append('images[]', this.form.images[i]);
                 }
 
              axios.post('/senddata', formData, config)
                .then(function (response) {
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this documentation for vform examples in GitHub that guides you to upload images with other input fields:

https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/example/upload.html

I think this example method solve your problem:

```
    selectFile (e) {
          const file = e.target.files[0]

          // Do some client side validation...

          this.form.file = file

          this.form.submit('post', '/upload', {
              // Transform form data to FormData
              transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
                return objectToFormData(data)
              }],

              onUploadProgress: e => {
                // Do whatever you want with the progress event
                // console.log(e)
              }
            })
            .then(({ data }) => {
              // ...
            })
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Pejman, I had seen that but not sure how to place the data inside this.form.submit('post'....